# Validation for input type file doesn't work in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have the following model:

```
 public class AModel
   {
      [ServerFileVerification( 1, FileType.TEST )]
      public HttpPostedFileBase[] Files
      {
         get;
         set;
      }
   }
```

The attribute:

```
public class ServerFileVerificationAttribute : RequiredAttribute 
{

   public ServerFileVerificationAttribute( ushort maximumNumberOfFiles, FileType fileType )
      {
         _maxFiles = maximumNumberOfFiles;
         _fileType = fileType;
      }

    public override bool IsValid( object value ) {
        HttpPostedFileBase[] files = value as HttpPostedFileBase[];
        string[] extensions = fileType == FileType.TEST ? {".zip"} : { ".txt" };

        foreach ( HttpPostedFileBase file in files ) {
           if(file == null ) continue;
           if ( !extensions.Contains( Path.GetExtension( file.FileName ) ) ) {
                     base.ErrorMessage = "The file " + file.FileName + " is invalid";
                     return false;
           }
        } 
    }
}
```

And the view:

```
@using ( Html.BeginForm( "Test", "Test", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" } ) ) {

   for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) { 
      @Html.TextBoxFor( item => item.Files[i], new { type = "file" } );
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor( item => item.Files[i] )
      <br />
   }

   <input type="submit" />
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
      public ActionResult Test( AModel model )
      {
         if ( ModelState.IsValid ) {
            return Redirect( "http://www.google.ro" );
         }

         return View( "Index", model );
      }
```

If I upload anything else than ZIP then should display an error, but it doesn't...

Where is my mistake ? I put ValidationMessageFor but it doesn't work ... Why ?

Comment: Set a breakpoint, walk through the code, explain what _does_ happen.

Comment: The breakpoint reaches `base.ErrorMessage = "The file " + file.FileName + " is invalid";` and that's strange. Because it doesn't display on html page ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the ModelState for the entry that has the error, is the key that contains the error listed under item.Files[i] or under item.Files? I suspect it should be the latter, in that case the code should read:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) { 
    @Html.TextBoxFor( item => item.Files[i], new { type = "file" } );
    <br />
}
@Html.ValidationMessageFor( item => item.Files ) //not Files[i]
```

Comment: So, is not possible to attach a validation message for separate input type file, right ?

Comment: Off the top of my head one way I know of would be to have a custom ModelBinder for the AModel. Override the OnModelUpdated and in it you can perform your validation there (not through the Attribute) and then you can add the error for each file manually using ModelState.AddModelError and then you can try to display them on the screen. Can't guarantee it works though :)

Answer (score 0):

Check ModelState in Controller like this

```
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       //Do the things that u want to do if there is no error  
    }
   else
    {
        return View("Create", Model);
    }
```

you will see the errors in page.